# MonoTouch and Xcode 4.3 from the App Store

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I removed Xcode 4.2 from my system and installed 4.3 from the App Store.

Now when I want to build my app in MonoDevelop it says

```
The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed.
```

Using Xcode I can build and run iOS apps just fine.

I tried reinstalling MonoTouch, but it will fail saying `XCode is missing`.

Any idea how to get this working again?

Comment: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/16/xcode-4-3-support/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 moved to a different directory, and MonoTouch can't find it anymore.

Yesterday we released a beta update that fixes this - just enable the beta channel in MonoDevelop (Preferences -> Updates) and then update to MonoDevelop (2.8.6.5) and MonoTouch (5.2.5).

Once we've been able to test the changes a bit more, we'll release these packages to the stable channel.