# Moving XCode location Breaks Monotouch compiling via MonoDevelop

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Having a similar problem as that described in [MonoTouch and Xcode 4.3 from the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326683/monotouch-and-xcode-4-3-from-the-app-store). I moved XCode to a different location and am getting:

```
The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed.
```

I've attempted to point MonoDevelop to the new location via "MonoDevelop -> Preferences -> SDK Locations -> Apple SDK", and while the GUI shows success when I browse to XCode.app, the new path isn't saved and I continue to receive errors.

I also tried to move it back to "/Applications/" but again, the setting doesn't take in MonoDevelop although the GUI shows that it successfully found the Apple SDK in the default location.

Note, I am running MonoDevelop version 2.8.8.4 at the moment.

Any suggestions? Should I downgrade to 2.8.6.5 Beta as suggested in [MonoTouch and Xcode 4.3 from the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326683/monotouch-and-xcode-4-3-from-the-app-store)?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/`?

Comment: Make sure you restart MonoDevelop after changing it's **SDK Location** setting. If that does not work please edit your question to include all your versions information (MonoTouch, OSX...) you can get them from MonoDevelop About dialog.

Comment: @jrtc27: Tried as you suggested, but it appears that the GUI only accepts a path to Xcode.app.

Comment: @poupou: Tried as you suggested, and **this worked**. Once the SDK Location setting (pointed to the new location of Xcode.app) was accepted, I quit MonoDevelop and started it again. Checked the setting under preferences, and the newly defined path was present. Compiled my MonoTouch app and all worked without a hitch. **Suggestion for the MD folks to reduce confusion:** _It would be helpful for either "restart" instructions to be given to the user upon changing such settings, or the preferences to be saved without a "restart"._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering for the benefit of other users who experience the same issue. @poupou's suggestion above (a comment to my original question) was what worked for me. Simply *"Make sure you restart MonoDevelop after changing it's SDK Location."*

Comment: A bug already exists for this https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3524 and I linked your question to it. Thanks for replying.